# Double Postback Using IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, postback

I'm using ASP.NET and I have a save button on webform.  When that save button is clicked (ONCE) and I'm using IE8 the event handler is executed twice.  If I use compatibility mode it works just fine.  In FF everything works just fine.  I tested IE8 on both Vista and windows 7 and get the same behavior.  IE7 works just fine.  Just curious is anyone has had a similar issue.

P.S. I am using an advanced layout system which positions and styles the controls based on a layout definition, so it isn't just a standard throw controls on a page setup.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples?

Comment: yes i'm interested in the part of the HTML and/or javascript that is responsible for initiating the postback.

Comment: I'm just using a standard event handler so the javascript is just __doPostBack('ctl00$Main$SaveButton','') for the onclick event. I'm still isolating the issue so I don't have a code example yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are using onserverclick on a button tag instead of using an asp.net button.  The solution was to set the type of the button to "button".  Before no type was set and I think it was defaulting to submit.

Changed

```
<button id="button1" runat="server" onserverclick="button1_OnClick" />
```

To

```
<button id="button1" runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="button1_OnClick" />
```

Now I do not get the double post back in IE8.

Comment: This is the perfect fix for this issue.

Comment: The button property UseSubmitBehavior="false" does the same thing. I had trouble with using type="button". It kept overriding back to 'submit', but this property made it stick. Old thread, but hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed a bug with similar symptoms which was caused by two form.submit() calls being made in the client-side javascript event handler for the button.

It appears the second form.submit() was being ignored by other browers but executed in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `jquery(formobj).trigger(submit)` this was changed to

```
jquery(formobj)[0].submit()
```

Note I am calling submit directly on the form instead of the jquery method 
hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to a similar problem I was having troubles with.
Since none of the previous solutions seemed to help me I thought I'd post my own solution.

The problem:

When using an asp button on a webform and using the OnClientClick to run a custom postback mechanism. The postback seems to happen twice (the second time without viewstate being applied)
e.g. :

```
function ok(){
        docustompostbackthing(); 
    }
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" Text="Ok" OnClientClick="ok();" cssClass="btn"/>
```

The solution:

Add a "return false;" after the js function call in the button's OnClientClick.
Adding it in the function itself doesn't do the trick.

e.g. :

```
   function ok(){
            docustompostbackthing(); 
        }
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" Text="Ok" OnClientClick="ok();return false;" cssClass="btn"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the html as it is rendered on the page:

Every time it's present

```
<img src=""/>
```

double postback can happen, for some browser...

If this is the trouble, you can resolve it setting a default, blank, image for every button

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/blank.gif"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the number of solutions.

It's not just **OnClientClick** that has issues, the **OnClick** event does a very similar thing in IE8 as well.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" Text="Ok" OnClick="ok();" cssClass="btn"/>
```

Can be updated to the following to avoid the second event being fired off.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOk" Text="Ok" OnClick="ok();return false;" cssClass="btn"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue happening in IE 11 and managed to fix it by adding type="button" to the button control.